# Adding properties to an array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an object that contains an array. While the items push through, what I am trying to do is set each item upon creation to have a `checked` value of `False`. Currently, I am seeing that this is setting the entire array to have a value of `false`. How can I modify this to have each item it's own `checked` value?

Desired output of items:

`["a", "checked": False], ["aa", "checked": False], ["aaa", "checked": False]`

```
// state objects
var state = {
    items: []
};

// state modification functions
function addItem(state, item) {
    item.name = item;
    state.items[item["checked"]] = "False";
    state.items.push(item);
    console.log(state.items);
}
```

Comment: Looks like you **really** should be using an object instead.

Comment: `items.push({value: "a", checked : false})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is an `Array` that contains `Objects`. Try this:

```
function addItem(state, item) {
    state.items.push({
      name   : item,
      checked: false
    })
}
```

You can then access `state.items[0]` to get the `{ name, checked }` object, or `state.items[0].name`/`state.items[0].checked` directly

Answer (score 0):

Some time easier is witch object

```
[{name: "a", checked: false}, {name: "aa", checked: false}]

// state objects
var state = {
    items: []
};

// state modification functions
function addItem(item) {
    state.items.push(item);
}

addItem({name: "a", checked: false})
```